# Null values returned in JSON response to query even though no null values present in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, database

[image: Data which should be returned by query]

I want to fetch the above data using php, I pass the email as a parameter and I want to retrieve all records which have user = email. However, the response I get is a bit odd. My main concern is the odd formatting and the presence of null values. I'm sure I have a minor mistake in the code somewhere, but as I am not that familiar with php I'm finding it difficult to identify the error.  The output looks like this:

```
{"0":"5phd6ure1lj941cv81o00tb4jr","id":null,"1":"8","stake":"8","2":"tester@tester.com","user":"tester@tester.com","3":"29","returns":"29","4":"(9\/X)","teams":"(9\/X)","5":"open","status":"open","bet":{"stake":null,"user":null,"returns":null,"teams":null,"status":null}}
```

These are the two files I use:

Get_Bets.php

```html
<?php

class Get_Bets {

   private $db;

   function __construct() {

 require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
 $this->db = new DB_Connect();


 $this->db->connect();


}


function __destruct() {
   
  }

  public function getUsersBets($email) {

   $conn=mysqli_connect("****", "***", "***","***");

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,stake,user,returns,teams,status FROM bet WHERE user = '$email'");

   $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
     
      $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      return $result;
       
    }
}
}
?>
```

Get_All_Bets.php

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $email = $_POST['email'];
 
    // include db handler
     require_once 'include/Get_Bets.php';


    $db = new Get_Bets();
 
    // response Array
    $response = $db->getUsersBets($email);
            $response["id"] = $bet["id"];
            $response["bet"]["stake"] = $row["stake"];
            $response["bet"]["user"] = $row["user"];
            $response["bet"]["returns"] = $row["returns"];
            $response["bet"]["teams"] = $row["teams"];
            $response["bet"]["status"] = $row["status"];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Get_All_Bets.php**, this code segment causes the error

```html
$response["id"] = $bet["id"];
$response["bet"]["stake"] = $row["stake"];
$response["bet"]["user"] = $row["user"];
$response["bet"]["returns"] = $row["returns"];
$response["bet"]["teams"] = $row["teams"];
$response["bet"]["status"] = $row["status"];
```

#### Remove it and the output will be O.K

Now let's discuss what's happening
after this line `$response = $db->getUsersBets($email);` the `$response` variable looks like that:

```js
{
  "0": "5phd6ure1lj941cv81o00tb4jr",
  "id": "5phd6ure1lj941cv81o00tb4jr",
  "1": "8",
  "stake": "8",
  "2": "tester@tester.com",
  "user": "tester@tester.com",
  "3": "29",
  "returns": "29",
  "4": "(9\/X)",
  "teams": "(9\/X)",
  "5": "open",
  "status": "open"
}
```

At line 1 in the wrong code `$response["id"] = $bet["id"];` you are overriding the key `id` in `$response` array with a new value, it's not O.K because there is no variable defined before with the name `$bet` so `$bet[$id]` will give you a null, that's why the `id` entry is null, the same applies for the the entry `$response["bet"]`, there is no previously defined variable with the name `$row` and that's why all the entries is null

P.S: in `mysqli_fetch_array` you can pass another parameter that indicates the fetch mode, if you don't need the numeric entries just call it like that `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, what if I want to return all the records with the user = email, so far it only returns the first one, but in the table there's 3 which should be returned

Comment: after I made those changes I get the following output : {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}

Comment: `$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)` returns the next row from the result set, to get all records you need make a loop until `mysqli_fetch_array` returns null, the code will be like `$all_rows = array(); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { $all_rows []= $row; } return $all_rows;`

Comment: detailed example of looping through the entire result set [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_proc)

Comment: I can't see any thing related to that `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":n‌​ull}` in your question, may be another detailed question for this **new** problem is o.k :D